# ember-auth sends OPTIONS requests instead of POST on my development machine

Tags: ember.js, sinatra

I have a Sinatra-based server which provides RESTful API for the service I'm working on. On my development machine in runs on `localhost:9393`.

At the same time my client application (built with `ember.js`) which uses `ember-auth` for user authentication runs on another port: `localhost:9000`.

Previously I set up both server and client on the same host:port and returned client app as static files. Authentication worked pretty well. According to the [official docs](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/docs) on SignIn I get POST request on the route I provided (`/signin`). But now I recieve **OPTIONS** request with no params whatsoever.

Some code from client (client is generated via Yeoman's ember-generator):

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>

    <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- build:js scripts/components.js -->
    <script src="components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="components/handlebars/handlebars.runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="components/ember/ember.js"></script>
    <script src="components/ember-data/ember-data-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="components/ember-auth/ember-auth.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/user.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/views/auth.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js(.tmp) scripts/templates.js -->
    <script src="scripts/compiled-templates.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var App = window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter:'DS.RESTAdapter'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  // I have no routes so far,
  // as I don't need them to test authentication itself
});

App.Auth = Ember.Auth.create({
  signInEndPoint: '/signin',
  signOutEndPoint: '/signout',
  tokenKey: 'auth_token',
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9393',
  tokenIdKey: 'user_id',
  userModel: 'App.User',
  sessionAdapter: 'cookie',
  modules: [
    'emberData', 'rememberable'
  ],
  rememberable: {
    tokenKey: 'remember_token',
    period: 7,
    autoRecall: true
  }
});
```

**user.js**

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  param: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**auth.js**

```
App.AuthView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'auth'
});

App.AuthSignInView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'signin',
  email: null,
  password: null,
  remember: true,
  submit: function(event, view){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    App.Auth.signIn({
      data:{
        email: this.get('email'),
        password: this.get('password'),
        remember: this.get('remember')
      }
    })
  }
});

App.AuthSignOutView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'signout',
  submit: function(event, view){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    App.Auth.signOut();
  }
});
```

**application.hbs**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
      {{view App.AuthView}}
    </div>
    <div class="span9">
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**auth.hbs**

```
{{#if App.Auth.signedIn}}
  {{view App.AuthSignOutView}}
{{else}}
  {{view App.AuthSignInView}}
{{/if}}
```

**signin.hbs**

```
<form>
  <label>Email</label>
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="view.email"}}
  <label>Password</label>
  {{view Ember.TextField type='password' valueBinding="view.password"}}
  {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="view.remember"}}
  <label>Remember me?</label>
  <hr />
  <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your REST API and client app are served from different origins; the protocol, host and port must be identical to follow [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Your browser is making a preflight OPTIONS request to determine if your server will allow [cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) from your client domain.

To get CORS working with your Sinatra server, you might want to check out [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) which will allow you to add middleware for setting the requisite access control headers. Once that is set up correctly, the expected POST request will be issued following the successful OPTIONS request.

For more on CORS, here are some resources I've found useful:

- http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/
- http://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working/
- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-CORS-AJAX-Requests-Between-jQuery-And-Node-js.htm

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.